# Polymorphic Nested Attributes not writing to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having issues with my application writing code to the database. I can see it in the parameters, but not in the database after it submits the form.

I created an address object I want to add to the course object.

Model

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address, :as => :addressable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
  // more code
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

Controller

```
class CoursesController < ApplicationController
  def course_params
  params.require(:course).permit(:short_description, :picture, :name, :cost, :description, :occurs_at, address_attributes: [:line1, :line2, :city, :state, :zip])
end

def create
  @course = current_user.courses.build(course_params)
  @course.build_address
  if @course.save
    flash[:success] = "Course created!"
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    @feed_items = []
    render 'static_pages/home'
  end
end

//No address controller
```

I tried to move the build_address call to inside the save, it seems to write to the database, but not actually associate the two...

Helper

```
module FormHelper
  def setup_course(course)
    course.address ||= Address.new
    course
  end
end
```

View

```
<%= form_for(setup_course(@course), html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :address do |address| %>
    <%= render :partial => 'shared/address', :locals => {:f => address} %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Database Console

```
Processing by CoursesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"KKDEbmm7vBFjDR6KPHn29ZbroA6FyLtkUaJhBu5kAELeL1Zs89WmonpDH8wCCqtFeiMDXxypJwsHv/ck5wbznA==", "course"=>{"name"=>"11", "short_description"=>"fdsaf0dsa3f032ds", "description"=>"f03dsaf1dsa01", "occurs_at"=>"<date>", "cost"=>"", "address_attributes"=>{"line1"=>"aa", "line2"=>"bb", "city"=>"cc", "state"=>"wa", "zip"=>"12345"}}, "commit"=>"Create Course"}
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
 (0.1ms)  begin transaction
 SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "courses" ("short_description", "name", "description", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["short_description", "fdsaf0dsa3f032ds"], ["name", "11"], ["description", "f03dsaf1dsa01"], ["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2016-05-27 02:33:31.234818"], ["updated_at", "2016-05-27 02:33:31.234818"]]
 SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "addresses" ("addressable_type", "addressable_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["addressable_type", "Course"], ["addressable_id", 17], ["created_at", "2016-05-27 02:33:31.247646"], ["updated_at", "2016-05-27 02:33:31.247646"]]
 (13.6ms)  commit transaction
```

I am running rails 4

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What does your CoursesController create action method look like?

Comment: Are you sure? The log shows records being inserted into both courses and addresses.

Comment: I have added the create in the courses_controller. @Anand

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the question that Anand asked. It is an issue with my create function.

Simple fix:

```
def create
  @course = current_user.courses.build(course_params)
  if @course.save
    flash[:success] = "Course created!"
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    @feed_items = []
    render 'static_pages/home'
  end
end
```